# Adding prefix to WooCommerce order number based on multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, prefix

From my previous question I am using [Adding prefix to WooCommerce order number if order has items from a specific product category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66760692/11987538) anwser code.

Now I want to extend this function for more categories, but I can't seem to find it out.

Now I want to add more if statements for the other categories. I am thinking of something like this:

```php
if ('category of first product in appearing in cart' === 'category id / category name') {

    $prefix = 'AB-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
elseif ('category of first product in appearing in cart' === 'category id / category name') {

    $prefix = 'CD-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
elseif ('category of first product in appearing in cart' === 'category id / category name') {

    $prefix = 'EF-';
    $new_order_id = $prefix . $order_id;
    return $new_order_id;

}
```

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback. For the overview of the topic I would like to display the code here, so everyone can understand more easely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend the code from [Adding prefix to WooCommerce order number if order has items from a specific product category](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66760692/11987538) answer code for multiple categories you can use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_order_number( $order_number, $order ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Product ID
        $product_id = $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();

        // Has term (product category)
        if ( has_term( array( 'categorie-1', 'categorie-2', 15, 16 ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'AB-' . $order_number;
        } elseif ( has_term( array( 'categorie-3', 'categorie-4' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'CD-' . $order_number;
        } elseif ( has_term( array( 'categorie-5', 'categorie-6' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            return 'EF-' . $order_number;
        }
    }
    
    return $order_number;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'filter_woocommerce_order_number', 10, 2 );
```

---

Using `if/elseif/else` you can add as many conditions as you prefer